# In R, extract repeated measures data scattered in different rows for all subjects

Tags: r, merge

I have an oddly formatted data set in which

Row 1 are gender and income data from subject 1 collected at visit 1

Row 2 are diabetes and hypertension history data from subject 1 collected at visit 2

Row 3 are gender and income data from subject 2 collected at visit 1

Row 4 are diabetes and hypertension history data from subject 2 collected at visit 2

and so on

I use R and want to combine all data from each subject so that there are 2 rows in the new data, row 1 has gender income diabetes and hypertension data for subject 1, and row 2 has data for subject 2. Could I get some help please?

Comment: Could you post a fictitious sample of data? (try using `dput`).  It's hard to know what exactly to do without knowing how your data appear (column names, etc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split and then combine.

```
(dat <- read.table("000.txt", head=F, as.is=T))
#    V1       V2     V3
# 1  Bob   Female  22445
# 2  Bob diabeteY HyperN
# 3 Lucy     Male  12345
# 4 Lucy diabeteN HyperY
dat01 <- dat[seq(1, nrow(dat), by=2),]
names(dat01) <- c("name", "gender","income")
dat01
#  name gender income
# 1  Bob Female  22445
# 3 Lucy   Male  12345
dat02 <- dat[seq(2, nrow(dat), by=2),]
names(dat02) <- c("name", "diabet", "hyper")
dat02
#  name   diabet  hyper
# 2  Bob diabeteY HyperN
# 4 Lucy diabeteN HyperY

(dat.final <- merge(dat01, dat02, by="name"))
#  name gender income   diabet  hyper
# 1  Bob Female  22445 diabeteY HyperN
# 2 Lucy   Male  12345 diabeteN HyperY
```